# How do I use MVC jQuery and Ajax together in order to return Json objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to be able to click a button, have a function in my controller return a JSON object that can be used on my page without the page reloading.

My controller:

```
//Dont know if HttpPost is right 
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult GetPinPoints() {
    return jsonobject;
}
```

I want to be able to call this and have it return a JSON object on a page in AJAX so I dont have to reload the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two Parts:

1) The Controller

```
public JsonResult GetPinPoints()
{
    var stuff = DoStuff();
    return Json(stuff);
}
```

2) The View (via JQuery)

```
$('#SomeButtonId').click(function () {

$.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/GetPinPoints',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        $('#someSuccessDiv').html(data).fadeIn();   
        //Do whatever here, just a poor mans example
    },
    error: function() {
        $('#someErrorDiv').html('Boo').fadeIn();
    }
});

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Ah, good to know. Is it just a matter of not needing the property because of the lack of input params or is there a technical reason? either way, I've updated my answer.

Comment: The `contentType` should describe the encoding format of the input parameters (jQuery's "data"). When you're working with ASP.NET WebForms' ScriptServices and PageMethods, you have to use JSON encoded data parameters and a content-type of `application/json` in order to coax JSON responses out of them.  Working with ASP.NET MVC, you can use `application/form-url-encoded` parameters instead, which is more common, yet still *respond* with JSON.

Answer (score 1):

In .ajax, use post method to call this method:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult GetPinPoints() {
    var obj = new ...
    return Json(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use the [protected `Json` method on the `Controller` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492986.aspx).  This will take an object and return it's JSON representation using in a [`JsonResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult.aspx).

Using your example:

```
public ActionResult GetPinPoints() {
    return Json(jsonobject);
}
```

If you do not like the way that ASP.NET MVC serializes your object into JSON, you can do it yourself, creating an `ActionResult` which will take your object (or the JSON you build) and write the contents back to the response stream.  Just make sure that the `ContentType` that you send back is of type `application/json` or `text/javascript`.

From there, you can use a call to [`getJSON` in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to get the results and then use the object however you wish.

Note that if you don't need anything overly complex, or your designs don't call for it, you do not need the `HttpPostAttribute`.